# how to avoid use of toString().getBytes("UTF-8") to avoid OOM error? Is there any better approach to convert to byte[] from StringWriter?

Tags: java, arrays, jvm, out-of-memory

I have a reporting web application which generates reports. The application gets data from a database and stores data into a `StringWriter` object. I have to get this data in a byte array format to create a csv file and send it to browser.

Below is the code snippet

```
 return new FileTransfer(fileName, reportType.getMimeType(),
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(generateCSV(reportType, grid, new DataList(), params).toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

where `generateCSV` returns a `StringWriter` object, then to convert it into byte array I am calling `toString` and then `getBytes()` method. Below is what the `generateCSV`  method looks like

```
StringWriter generateCSV(ReportType reportType, GridConfig grid, DataList dataList, String params) {......}
```

The problem is that when my report has huge records (more than 1 million), the `getBytes()` method fails with

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

The whole report data when converted to String object has a huge number of characters (billions of it). The `.getBytes("UTF-8")` method convert it into array, each array element as one character. And for 1 million records, the character are exceeding the MAX JVM ARRAY size limit (https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/requested-array-size-exceeds-vm-limit).

Now how can I avoid use of `toString().getBytes("UTF-8")` to avoid OOM error? Is there any better approach to convert to byte array from `StringWriter`?

Comment: Does the `generateCSV` method directly generates the CSV into a `StringWriter`?

Comment: What is `FileTransfer`? Does it really mandate a `ByteArrayInputStream`? Or does it support a `Reader` (then you could use `StringReader`) or at least arbitrary `InputStream`s (in that case, Apache Commons has a `ReaderInputStream`)?

Comment: Consider using temporary files and input/output stream (or reader) instead of keeping everything in memory.

Comment: "I have to get this data in a byte array format to create a csv file and send it to browser". I doubt that statement is true. If you are writing out text, you want to write as a properly encoding byte stream.

Comment: Hi  @Lino yes generateCSV method generates report data into StringWriter object.

Comment: @Holger, FileTransfer is org.directwebremoting.io class, we are using this to download report in browser.    front end code :this.svc.downloadCSVReport(params.fileType, this.getGridConfig(), this.getParams(Ext.toArray(this.paramNames)), this.timezoneField.getValue(), {
                    ...});

Answer (score 1):

The StringWriter holds its content in the memory. So it's not a good approach to use it with large files.

You should try to chunk the File directly to the InputStream without the StringWriter in the middle. 
What about your own `InputStream` implementation which reads and convert the file to csv on the fly.

Can you show us the generateCSV method?

Comment: protected StringWriter generateCSV(ReportType reportType, GridConfig grid, DataList dataList, String params) {
        Header header = getReportHeaderData(reportType, null);
        RecordList list = getReportData(reportType, grid, params);
       dataList.setHEADER(header);
        StringWriter out = new StringWriter(); Character separator = reportHelper.getListSeparator();
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(out, separator);
  //where CSVWriter is public class CSVWriter extends au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter
  //logic to fetch report data from database
 return out; }

Answer (score 1):

It’s strange to receive the result of `generateCSV` as a `StringWriter`; the preferred solution would be to let the method write to a target while generating, so you don’t have the entire contents in memory.

In either case, you should resort to the [`FileTransfer(String, String mimeType, OutputStreamLoader)`](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/javadoc/org/directwebremoting/io/FileTransfer.html#FileTransfer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.directwebremoting.io.OutputStreamLoader)) constructor, to receive the target `OutputStream` when it is time to write the actual data.

When you can’t avoid the intermediate `StringWriter`, you should at least avoid calling `toString` on it, as constructing a `String` implies creating a copy of the entire buffer.

So a solution could look like:

```
return new FileTransfer(fileName, reportType.getMimeType(), new OutputStreamLoader() {
    public void close() {}
    public void load(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        // the best would be to let generateCSV write to out directly
        // otherwise use:
        StringBuffer sb = generateCSV(reportType, grid, new DataList(), params).getBuffer();
        Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")
        final int bufSize = 8192;
        for(int s = 0, e; s < sb.length(); s = e) {
            e = Math.min(sb.length(), s + bufSize);
            w.write(sb.substring(s, e));
        }
        w.flush(); // let the caller close the OutputStream
    }
});
```

An alternative to `StringWriter` would be [`CharArrayWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/CharArrayWriter.html), which has a [`writeTo​(Writer out)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/CharArrayWriter.html#writeTo-java.io.Writer-), which eliminates the need to implement a manual copying loop and might be even more efficient. But, as said, refactoring `generateCSV` to write directly to a target would be even better.